# Linux: find MAC Address for unconfigured card

Tags: linux, mac-address

I have a linux system for which I want to create my own udev rules for the nic. Currently there are no rules, so no ethX is configured. I can't do `ifconfig` (it is not showing any interfaces besides `lo`) or grep eth in `/var/log/*`. Is there a way I can find out the mac address from within my system without looking at the hardware?

Comment: Load the relevant driver with `modprobe`, then it'll show up in `ifconfig` output.

Comment: Have you tried ifconfig -a?

Comment: Blush - the `-a` Option is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try (ifconfig does not display interfaces which are down otherwise)

```
ifconfig -a
```

of

```
ip address show
```

Answer (score 0):

install lshw in your system first. then sudo lshw and examine the output. look for the network sections. mac address is called serial: in the output. or you can look for Ethernet. the nics may not be called ethX (logical name) depending on your distribution, however.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to find the MAC of your devices is to use the `ip(8)` command. They'll show up regardless its current configuration status.

[Avoid the use of ifconfig](http://inai.de/2008/0219-ifconfig-sucks.php).

```
# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

As @MadHatter noted in a comment, the required modules for the device must be present and loaded in the kernel.